# maven failed to deploy - could not find artifact

Tags: java, maven, github, continuous-integration

Ill be starting with saying that I have tried numerous solutions mentioned in other awnsers but I get the feeling there is something wrong with my pom file.

I want to publish certain modules of my maven project to github packagaes. So in my main pom file I added the following:

```xml
    <distributionManagement>
        <repository>
            <id>github</id>
            <name>GitHub Packages</name>
            <url>https://maven.pkg.github.com/tomkeuper/custom-generators</url>
        </repository>
    </distributionManagement>
```

In my settings.xml file thats in my maven home dir I put my bearer token for validation and for testing purposes I gave it all the github classic token permissions.

```xml
<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd%22%3E">
      
  <servers>
    <server>
      <id>github</id>
      <configuration>
        <httpHeaders>
          <property>
            <name>Authorization</name>
            <value>Bearer token</value>
          </property>
        </httpHeaders>
      </configuration>
    </server>
  </servers>
</settings>
```

Looking at other examples and the github documentation I believe this not to be the problem as it looks al correct.

But when executing maven deploy from within intellij I get the following error

```
Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.7:deploy (default-deploy) on project bedwars2023: Failed to deploy artifacts: Could not find artifact com.andrei1058.bedwars:bedwars2023:pom:23.3.1-BETA2 in github
```

Full maven deploy -e log: https://pastebin.com/bHzDtpx6

My complete pom file looks like this https://github.com/tomkeuper/BedWars1058/blob/api-fixes/pom.xml

and if someone is wondering the installed version of maven is 3.8.3 but the issue also happens when being executed with github actions.

Comment: First I would suggest to. upgrade all your used plugins to the most recent versions because you seemed to be used very ancient versions of plugin https://maven.apache.org/plugins/

Comment: I've just checked but the compiler plugin and javadoc plugin are already on the lastest version (as of feb 2023)

Comment: Also when manually adding the deploy/install plugin and setting to latest version it still has the same error